# Bring Silverlight pop up to the front

Tags: silverlight-4.0

we are popping up a childwindow in a timer.we would like to show the popup on top of all other applications if the user is working on any other apps.Is there any way to get any user notification that the popup is behind ? Any way to bring the silverlight app to the front ? we are using silverlight 4.0

Comment: Please think carefully before doing this. Google for "stealing focus" and consider how your users will feel when their work is interrupted with your all-important announcement. Jeff Atwood, one of this site's founders, had this to say on the matter: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/please-dont-steal-my-focus.html

Comment: I concur - focus-stealing is bad. How about using SL4 "toast" notification? You'll get a nice, unobtrusive, non-focus-stealing "popup" in the lower-right corner of the screen.  You can customize it, bind data to it...

Comment: I was also planning to use the SL 4 toast notification.But unfortunately it works only with out of browser.

Comment: Any other way to show a taskbar button flashing or something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible.

I think your only hope is notifying them with a sound.